Did Krishna marry before Subhadra?
Did krishna marry earlier than Subhadra married arjuna?

Yes. Long before. Krishna's sons Pradyumna, Samba and Charudeshna attended the Draupadi Sayamavara.

Samkarshana, Vasudeva, Rukmini’s brave son, Samba, Charudeshna, Sarana, Gada, Akrura, Satyaki, the immensely powerful Uddhava, Hridika’s son Kritavarma,

177, Draupadi Swaymavara Parva, Mahabharata.
